# Solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}[\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}-\sqrt{2(x^2+x)} ]$ without using L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}[\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}-\sqrt{2(x^2+x)} ] = \\
\sqrt{(2x-1)(x+1)}-\sqrt{2x(x+1)}= \\
\sqrt{2x-1}\cdot \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{2x}\cdot \sqrt{x+1}=\\
\sqrt{(x+1)}(\sqrt{(2x-1)}-\sqrt{(2x)})= \\
???$$

What do I do next? How do I solve this?

Comment: Hint:  $\sqrt a-\sqrt b=(a-b)/(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may write, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}-\sqrt{2(x^2+x)}
\\\\&=\frac{[\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}-\sqrt{2(x^2+x)}][\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}+\sqrt{2(x^2+x)}] }{\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}+\sqrt{2(x^2+x)}}
\\\\&=-\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}+\sqrt{2(x^2+x)}}
\\\\&=-\frac{1+1/x}{\sqrt{2+1/x-1/x^2}+\sqrt{2+2/x}}
\end{align}
$$ then one may conclude easily.